# Django: getting just first element, not all using filter

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have three models that looks like this:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Stream(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    blog = models.ManyToManyField(Blog, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.user
```

In `steam` object i have two `blog` objects. In first `blog` object i have three `blogpost` in the second is the same.

Then i create queryset:

```
stream = Stream.objects.get(pk=1)
blog = Blog.objects.filter(stream=stream)
print (blog)
<QuerySet [<Blog: Blog object>, <Blog: Blog object>]>
blogpost = BlogPost.objects.filter(blog=blog)
print (blogpost)
<QuerySet [<BlogPost: BlogPost object>, <BlogPost: BlogPost object>, <BlogPost: BlogPost object>]>
```

In `blogpost` I get only from first `blog` object elements not from all. Anybody know why it happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do it with `__in` lookup

```
blog = Blog.objects.filter(stream=stream)
blogpost = BlogPost.objects.filter(blog__in=blog)
```